# Heatmap with varying y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

I would like to create a visualization like the upper part of [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0xBQ.jpg) image. Essentially, a heatmap where each point in time has a fixed number of components but these components are anchored to the y axis by means of labels (that I can supply) rather than by their first index in the heatmap's matrix.

I am aware of pcolormesh, but that does not seem to give me the y-axis functionality I seek.

Lastly, I am also open to solutions in R, although a Python option would be *much* preferable.

Comment: Do it with one large image and fill the non-colored regions with nans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure if I understand your meaning correctly, but by looking at the picture you have linked, you might be best off with a roll-your-own solution.

First, you need to create an array with the heatmap values so that you have on row for each label and one column for each time slot. You fill the array with nans and then write whatever heatmap values you have to the correct positions.

Then you need to trick `imshow` a bit to scale and show the image in the correct way.

For example:

```
# create some masked data
a=cumsum(random.random((20,200)), axis=0)
X,Y=meshgrid(arange(a.shape[1]),arange(a.shape[0]))
a[Y<15*sin(X/50.)]=nan
a[Y>10+15*sin(X/50.)]=nan

# draw the image along with some curves
imshow(a,interpolation='nearest',origin='lower',extent=[-2,2,0,3])
xd = linspace(-2, 2, 200)
yd = 1 + .1 * cumsum(random.random(200)-.5) 
plot(xd, yd,'w',linewidth=3)
plot(xd, yd,'k',linewidth=1)
axis('normal')
```

Gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, with minor adaptations I have managed to get this to do exactly what I needed!